# Ionic Firebase Analytics is not working correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-analytics

I made a service for log event on firebase, and I'm calling a function from my login page, but nothing happens. When I open Firebase Dashboard -> Events, I can't see my custom event. There is my service.

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AnalyticsFirebase } from '@ionic-native/analytics-firebase/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EventLoggerService {

  constructor(
    private analyticsFirebase: AnalyticsFirebase,
    public plt: Platform
    ) {
  }

  makeLog(name: string,page: any){
    const eventParams = {};
    eventParams['page'] = page;
    this.analyticsFirebase.logEvent(name, eventParams)
      .then(() => console.log('Event successfully tracked'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error tracking event:', err));
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you already make sure that firebase parses your google.json file?

Comment: Yes, firebase storage and database is working.